# JavaScript Performance: Multiple variables or one object?

Tags: javascript, performance

this is just a simple performance question, helping me understand the javascript engine.
for this I'm was wondering, what is faster: declaring multiple variables for certain values or using one object containing multiple values.

example:

```
var x = 15;
var y = 300;
```

vs.

```
var sizes = { x: 15, y: 300 };
```

this is just a very simple example, could of course differ in a real project.
does this even matter?

Comment: The difference is not as slight as it seems, but the difference is small enough that it does not concern someone who is not invested in performance. The benchmarks themselves that compare this situation are flawed in that they use tight loops, where JIT can heavily optimize both and cause similar performance. Instead, we must eliminate the tight loop to get a better feel for real world applications. Please see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61584292/5601591

Answer (score 40, accepted):

A complete answer for that question would be really long. So I'll try to explain a few things only. First, maybe most important fact, even if you declare a variable with `var`, it depends where you do that. In a global scope, you implicitly would also write that variable in an object, most browsers call it `window`. So for instance

```
// global scope
var x = 15;

console.log( window.x ); // 15
```

If we do the same thing within the context of a function things change. Within the context of a function, we would write that variable name into its such called 'Activation Object'. That is, an internal object which the js engine handles for you. All formal parameters, function declarations and variables are stored there.

Now to answer your actual question: Within the context of a function, its always the fastest possible access to have variables declared with `var`. This again is not necesarrily true if we are in the global context. The global object is very huge and its not really fast to access anything within.

If we store things within an object, its still very fast, but not as fast as variables declared by `var`. Especially the access times do increase. But nonetheless, we are talking about micro and nanoseconds here (in modern browser implementations). Old'ish browsers, especially IE6+7 have huge performance penalties when accessing object properties.

If you are really interested in stuff like this, I highyl recommend the book '**High Performance Javascript**' by Nicholas C. Zakas. He measured lots of different techniques to access and store data in ECMAscript for you.

Again, performance differences for object lookups and variables declared by `var` is almost not measureable in modern browsers. Old'ish Browsers like FF3 or IE6 do show a fundamental slow performance for object lookups/access.

Comment: As an anecdote of when this actually matters: wrote an educational image effects function that iterated through each pixel on a canvas (1920 x 1080 ish) in real time, and in this case there was a significant improvement in fps (increased by about 25%) switching to local variables over object properties.

Comment: Interesting to read in 2017. What browsers are we talking about?
Actually any browser by now is very sophisticated in caching lookup-trees end Environment Records and stuff, so actually, I'd really guess there is something "strange" in your code which hinders caching mechanisms to work properly.

Answer (score 6):

`foo_bar` is always faster than `foo.bar` in every modern browser (IE11+/Edge and any version of Chrome, FireFox, and Safari) and NodeJS so long as you see performance as holistic (which I recommend you should). After millions of iterations in a tight loop, `foo.bar` may approach (but never surpass) the same ops/s as `foo_bar` due to the wealth of correct branch predictions. Notwithstanding, `foo.bar` incurs a ton more overhead during both JIT compilation and execution because it is so much more complex of an operation. JavaScript that features no tight loops benefits an extra amount from using `foo_bar` because, in comparison, `foo.bar` would have a much higher overhead:savings ratio such that there was extra overhead involved in the JIT of `foo.bar` just to make `foo.bar` a little faster in a few places. Granted, all JIT engines intelligently try to guess how much effort should be put into optimizing what to minimize needless overhead, but there is still a baseline overhead incurred by processing `foo.bar` that can never be optimized away.

**Why?** JavaScript is a highly dynamic language, where there is costly overhead associated with every object. It was originally a tiny scripting executed line-by-line and still exhibits line-by-line execution behavior (it's not executed line-by-line anymore but, for example, one can do something evil like `var a=10;eval('a=20');console.log(a)` to log the number 20). JIT compilation is highly constrained by this fact that JavaScript must observe line-by-line behavior. Not everything can be anticipated by JIT, so all code must be slow in order for extraneous code such as is shown below to run fine.

```js
(function() {"use strict";
// chronological optimization is very poor because it is so complicated and volatile
var setTimeout=window.setTimeout;
var scope = {};
scope.count = 0;
scope.index = 0;
scope.length = 0;

function increment() {
 // The code below is SLOW because JIT cannot assume that the scope object has not changed in the interum
 for (scope.index=0, scope.length=17; scope.index<scope.length; scope.index=scope.index+1|0)
   scope.count = scope.count + 1|0;
 scope.count = scope.count - scope.index + 1|0;
}

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log( scope );
}, 713);

for(var i=0;i<192;i=i+1|0)
  for (scope.index=11, scope.length=712; scope.index<scope.length; scope.index=scope.index+1|0)
    setTimeout(increment, scope.index);
})();
```

```js
(function() {"use strict";
// chronological optimization is very poor because it is so complicated and volatile
var setTimeout=window.setTimeout;
var scope_count = 0;
var scope_index = 0;
var scope_length = 0;

function increment() {
 // The code below is FAST because JIT does not have to use a property cache
 for (scope_index=0, scope_length=17; scope_index<scope_length; scope_index=scope_index+1|0)
   scope_count = scope_count + 1|0;
 scope_count = scope_count - scope_index + 1|0;
}

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log({
    count: scope_count,
    index: scope_index,
    length: scope_length
  });
}, 713);

for(var i=0;i<192;i=i+1|0)
  for (scope_index=4, scope_length=712; scope_index<scope_length; scope_index=scope_index+1|0)
    setTimeout(increment, scope_index);
})();
```

Performing a one sample z-interval by running each code snippet above 30 times and seeing which one gave a higher count, I am 90% confident that the later code snippet with pure variable names is faster than the first code snippet with object access between 76.5% and 96.9% of the time. As another way to analyze the data, there is a 0.0000003464% chance that the data I collected was a fluke and the first snippet is actually faster. Thus, I believe it is reasonable to infer that `foo_bar` is faster than `foo.bar` because there is less overhead.

Don't get me wrong. Hash maps are very fast because many engines feature advanced property caches, but there will still always be enough extra overhead when using hash maps. Observe.

```js
(function(){"use strict"; // wrap in iife

// This is why you should not pack variables into objects
var performance = window.performance; 

var iter = {};
iter.domino = -1; // Once removed, performance topples like a domino
iter.index=16384, iter.length=16384;
console.log(iter);


var startTime = performance.now();

// Warm it up and trick the JIT compiler into false optimizations
for (iter.index=0, iter.length=128; iter.index < iter.length; iter.index=iter.index+1|0)
  if (recurse_until(iter, iter.index, 0) !== iter.domino)
    throw Error('mismatch!');

// Now that its warmed up, drop the cache off cold and abruptly
for (iter.index=0, iter.length=16384; iter.index < iter.length; iter.index=iter.index+1|0)
  if (recurse_until(iter, iter.index, 0) !== iter.domino)
    throw Error('mismatch!');

// Now that we have shocked JIT, we should be running much slower now
for (iter.index=0, iter.length=16384; iter.index < iter.length; iter.index=iter.index+1|0)
  if (recurse_until(iter, iter.index, 0) !== iter.domino)
    throw Error('mismatch!');

var endTime=performance.now();

console.log(iter);
console.log('It took ' + (endTime-startTime));

function recurse_until(obj, _dec, _inc) {
  var dec=_dec|0, inc=_inc|0;
  var ret = (
    dec > (inc<<1) ? recurse_until(null, dec-1|0, inc+1|0) :
    inc < 384 ? recurse_until :
    // Note: do not do this in production. Dynamic code evaluation is slow and
    //  can usually be avoided. The code below must be dynamically evaluated to
    //  ensure we fool the JIT compiler.
    recurse_until.constructor(
      'return function(obj,x,y){' +
          // rotate the indices
          'obj.domino=obj.domino+1&7;' +
          'if(!obj.domino)' +
          'for(var key in obj){' +
              'var k=obj[key];' +
              'delete obj[key];' +
              'obj[key]=k;' +
              'break' +
          '}' +
          'return obj.domino' +
      '}'
    )()
  );
  if (obj === null) return ret;
  
  recurse_until = ret;
  return obj.domino;
}

})();
```

For a performance comparison, observe pass-by-reference via an array and local variables.

```js
// This is the correct way to write blazingly fast code
(function(){"use strict"; // wrap in iife

var performance = window.performance; 

var iter_domino=[0,0,0]; // Now, domino is a pass-by-reference list
var iter_index=16384, iter_length=16384;


var startTime = performance.now();

// Warm it up and trick the JIT compiler into false optimizations
for (iter_index=0, iter_length=128; iter_index < iter_length; iter_index=iter_index+1|0)
  if (recurse_until(iter_domino, iter_index, 0)[0] !== iter_domino[0])
    throw Error('mismatch!');

// Now that its warmed up, drop the cache off cold and abruptly
for (iter_index=0, iter_length=16384; iter_index < iter_length; iter_index=iter_index+1|0)
  if (recurse_until(iter_domino, iter_index, 0)[0] !== iter_domino[0])
    throw Error('mismatch!');

// Now that we have shocked JIT, we should be running much slower now
for (iter_index=0, iter_length=16384; iter_index < iter_length; iter_index=iter_index+1|0)
  if (recurse_until(iter_domino, iter_index, 0)[0] !== iter_domino[0])
    throw Error('mismatch!');

var endTime=performance.now();

console.log('It took ' + (endTime-startTime));

function recurse_until(iter_domino, _dec, _inc) {
  var dec=_dec|0, inc=_inc|0;
  var ret = (
    dec > (inc<<1) ? recurse_until(null, dec-1|0, inc+1|0) :
    inc < 384 ? recurse_until :
    // Note: do not do this in production. Dynamic code evaluation is slow and
    //  can usually be avoided. The code below must be dynamically evaluated to
    //  ensure we fool the JIT compiler.
    recurse_until.constructor(
      'return function(iter_domino, x,y){' +
          // rotate the indices
          'iter_domino[0]=iter_domino[0]+1&7;' +
          'if(!iter_domino[0])' +
          'iter_domino.push( iter_domino.shift() );' +
          'return iter_domino' +
      '}'
    )()
  );
  if (iter_domino === null) return ret;
  
  recurse_until = ret;
  return iter_domino;
}

})();
```

JavaScript is very different from other languages in that benchmarks can easily be a performance-sin when misused. What really matters is what should *in theory* run the fastest accounting for everything in JavaScript. The browser you are running your benchmark in right now may fail to optimize for something that a later version of the browser will optimize for.

Further, browsers are guided in the direction that we program. If everyone used CodeA that makes no performance sense via pure logic but is really fast (44Kops/s) only in a certain browser, other browsers will lean towards optimizing CodeA and CodeA may eventually surpass 44Kops/s in all browsers. On the other hand, if CodeA were really slow in all browsers (9Kops/s) but was very logical performance-wise, browsers would be able to take advantage of that logic and CodeA may soon surpass 900Kops/s in all browsers. Ascertaining the logical performance of code is very simple and very difficult. One must put themself in the shoes of the computer and imagine one has an infinite amount of paper, an infinite supply of pencils, and an infinite amount of time, **and no ability to interpret the purpose/intention of the code**. How can you structure your code to fare the best under such hypothetical circumstances?  For example, hypothetically, the hash maps incurred by `foo.bar` would be a bit slower than doing `foo_bar` because `foo.bar` would require looking at the table named foo and finding the property named bar. You could put your finger on the location of the bar property to cache it, but the  overhead of looking through the table to find bar costed time.

Answer (score 2):

You are definitely micro-optimizing.  I wouldn't worry about it until there is a demonstrable performance bottleneck, and you have narrowed the issue to using multiple vars vs a object with properties.

Logically thinking about it using the object approach requires three variable creations, one for the object, and one for each property on the object, vs 2 for just declaring variables.  So having the object will have a higher memory approach.  However, it is probably more efficient to pass an object to a method, than n > 1 variables to a method, since you only need to copy 1 value (javascript is pass by value).  This also has implications for keeping track of the lexical scoping of the objects; i.e. passing less things to methods will use less memory.

however, i doubt the performance differences will even be quantifiable by any profiler.

Comment: I'm not expert myself but I'd agree - especially when you consider that your runtime code (javascript) is going to be run by several javascript interpretors (all the different kinds of browsers out there). What might be best for one may not be best for another.

Answer (score 2):

Theory or questions like "*What you are ..hmm.. doing, dude?*", of course, can appear here as an answers.  But I dont think it's good approach.

I just created two test benchs:

---

1. Specific, http://jsben.ch/SvNyw for global scope

It shows, for example, that on 07/2017 in **Chromium** based browsers (**Vivaldi**, **Opera**, **Google Chrome** and other) to achieve max performance there are preferable to use **var**. It works about 25% faster for reading values and 10% faster for writing ones.

Under **Node.js** there're about the same results - because of same JS engine.

In **Opera** Presto (**12**.18) there're the similar percentage test results as in chromium-based browsers.

In (modern) **Firefox** there is other and strange picture. Reading of global scope var is around the same as reading of object property, and **writing** of global scope var is dramatically slower than writing obj.prop (around twice slower). It seems like a bug.

For testing under **IE/Edge** or any others you are welcome.

---

2. Normal case, http://jsben.ch/5UvSZ for in-function local scope

In both Chromium based browsers and Mozilla Firefox you can see **huge domination of simple var performance** according to object property access. Local simple variables are several times (!) faster than dealing with object properties.

---

So,

if you need maximize some critical JavaScript code performance:

- in browser - you can forced to make different optimizations for several browsers. *I dont recommend!* Or you can select some "favorite" browser, optimize your code for it and do not see what freezes happens in other ones. Not wery good, but is the way.
- in browser, again - do you really need to optimize this way? May be something wrong in your algorithm / code logic?
- in **highload** Node.js module (or other highload calcs) - well, try to minimize object "dots", with minimized damage to quality/readability of course - use `var`.

The safe optimization trick for any case - when you have too much operations with `obj.subobj.*` you can do `var subobj = obj.subobj;` and operate with `subobj.*`. This can ever improve readability.

In any case, think what do you need and do and make real bechmarks of you highload code.