# Objects as variable containers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, frontend

Recently I saw something like this in some code from a project I'm working on...

```
var domObjects = {
  $body: $('body'),
  $someDiv: $('.some-div'),
  $someOtherDiv: $('.some-other-div')
}

var constants = {
  CONST_ONE: 'some value',
  CONST_TWO: 'some value',
  CONST_THREE: 'some value'
}
```

As you already may notice this code intents to replace code like this:

```
var $body = $('body'),
    $someDiv = $('.some-div'),
    $someOtherDiv = $('.some-other-div');

var CONST_ONE = 'some value',
    CONST_TWO = 'some value',
    CONST_THREE = 'some value';
```

The idea behind this is to wrap the variables in a more "semantic" object so it could be easier to use, but I really have my doubts about to create an object just for cosmetic reasons.

- It this ok?
- There is any real advantage if I do the declarations this way?
- There is any disadvantage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly fine: JavaScript lets you put any values inside of an object, which means you can use JS objects as "containers" for things like common variables or constants.

It's mostly a matter of personal preference. A construction like this is easier to pass around, so you don't constantly "requery" for things like $body or $document, but it can also hide what's in the object, so you don't know how much "room" your function input is taking up.

Is that a problem? Maybe, maybe not, that's up to whoever writes/uses the code. This question is (beyond the "is this okay" part, which it totally is) mostly a matter of opinion, guided by code style guides, and considerations about how to pack commonly used references.

There is one instance where this style makes a difference, and that's when unrolling switches. For instance:

```
function(input) {
  var a = "cat",
      b = "cow",
      c = "goldfish";
  console.log("testing multiple case identities...");
  switch(input) {
    case "small": return a;
    case "large": return b;
    case "aquatic": 
    case "fish": return c;
  };
  return false;
}
```

Instead of this check-by-check, we can be immediate:

```
var values = {
  "small": generateSmallAnimal,
  "large": generateLargeAnimal,
  "aquatic": generateFish
  "fish": generateFish
};

function(input) {
  console.log("direct jump...");
  return values[input]();
}
```

Done, no multiple case checks, just an immediate jump to the right thing.

Answer (score 3):

This style is not used because it's faster to work with since more typing is needed to access the variables, consider `constants.const1` instead of just typing `const1`.

However, I like the style for at least these reasons:

- The variables are '*scoped*'(so there's less possibility of a global collision)
- They are semantically encapsulated where they belong - which gives an explanation into which group they belong - It's easier for another dev who picks this up to make meaning of what those variables are
- They are easier to work with - If you want to capture all the properties of a group - e.g consider the object is `department`, you just iterate over the `department` which has all the relevant info you need

---

The DOM objects *might* be a little unnecessary to be put within an object, as for the rest I fully agree into wrapping them in an object like that.

Comment: although it should be noted it *is* faster to work with in the context of unrolling switches (either `switch` of `if/else` cascades).

Answer (score 2):

> It this ok?

Yes, this is totally okay. I have seen many JS libs group **related** values into an object. For example, many jQuery plugins store the configuration values into a `settings` object.

> There is any real advantage if I do the declarations this way?

To me the major advantage is that related values are semantically grouped together. Imagine when we are coding in a modern IDE, I can simply type the `objectName` and `[dot]` to let the IDE lists out the variables of that particular group.

> There is any disadvantage?

There is a performance difference as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789969/javascript-performance-mutiple-variables-or-one-object), though it is not so important with modern browsers.